# How can I solve this nature log equation?

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

$ln(x+2)=e^{(x-4)}$
Is there any way to solve this equation without graphing or using GDC ?

Thank you

Comment: I think the W Lambert function is required.

Comment: Since $ \ \ln(x+2) \ $ can't be split up into anything else, it's going to be mighty hard to isolate $ \ x \ $ .  You can get to $$ \ x \ = \ e^{e^{x-4}} \ - \ 2 \ . $$   I think this requires a numerical solution (there are two, actually).

Comment: Have you tried mathematica or maple?

Comment: I have not seen a closed form solutions for such equations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ross Millikan answered, the presence of  two layers of exponentials does not give any hope for analytical solutions and numerical methods are required.

Consider $$f(x)=e^{x-4}-\log (x+2)$$ $$f'(x)=e^{x-4}-\frac{1}{x+2}$$ $$f''(x)=e^{x-4}+\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$$ The first derivative cancels for $$x_*=W\left(e^6\right)-2\approx 2.49666 $$ ($W(z)$ being Lambert function); at this point $$f(x_*)=\frac{1}{W\left(e^6\right)}+W\left(e^6\right)-6\approx -1.28095 < 0$$ On the other side, by inspection, $f(-1)=\frac{1}{e^5}$ is a small positive number; the second derivative being always positive, there are two roots on each side of $x_*$.

Let us use Newton method.

For the first root, let us select $x_0=-1$; the successive iterates will then be $$x_1=-0.993216345093696$$ $$x_2=-0.993192968155096$$ $$x_3=-0.993192967879949$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant digits.

For the second root, let select $x_0=5$ (twice the value of $x_*$); the successive iterates will then be $$x_1=4.70009929479913$$ $$x_2=4.64012704349585$$ $$x_3=4.63807063896736$$ $$x_4=4.63806831105211$$ $$x_5=4.63806831104913$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised.  It becomes $x+2=e^{e^{x-4}}$ and the mix of polynomials and exponentials is usually intractable without the W function.  Having two layers of exponential is worse.  The fact that [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(x%2B2)%3De%5E(x-4)) gives only numeric answers says it could not solve it algebraically, either.  It finds $4.63806831104913$ and $-0.993192967879949$ as approximate solutions.

Comment: Which means the only for to solve this equation is to use graphing calculator? (we haven't learned W function yet)

Comment: The W function is not very popular.  Without it(and maybe even with it) your only approach is numeric.  Many equations are that way.  You can do the calculations by hand, but they are sometimes tedious.